# Gini Coefficient in Julia: Efficient and Accurate Code

Tags: statistics, distribution, julia, inequality

I'm trying to implement the following formula in Julia for calculating the [Gini coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) of a wage distribution:

[image]

where   [image]

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using for this:

```
# Takes a array where first column is value of wages
# (y_i in formula), and second column is probability
# of wage value (f(y_i) in formula).
function gini(wagedistarray)
    # First calculate S values in formula
    for i in 1:length(wagedistarray[:,1])
        for j in 1:i
            Swages[i]+=wagedistarray[j,2]*wagedistarray[j,1]
        end
    end

    # Now calculate value to subtract from 1 in gini formula
    Gwages = Swages[1]*wagedistarray[1,2]
    for i in 2:length(Swages)
        Gwages += wagedistarray[i,2]*(Swages[i]+Swages[i-1])
    end

    # Final step of gini calculation
    return giniwages=1-(Gwages/Swages[length(Swages)])          
end

wagedistarray=zeros(10000,2)                                 
Swages=zeros(length(wagedistarray[:,1]))                    

for i in 1:length(wagedistarray[:,1])
   wagedistarray[i,1]=1
   wagedistarray[i,2]=1/10000
end


@time result=gini(wagedistarray)
```

It gives a value of near zero, which is what you expect for a completely equal wage distribution. However, it takes quite a long time: 6.796 secs.

Any ideas for improvement?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
function gini(wagedistarray)
    nrows = size(wagedistarray,1)
    Swages = zeros(nrows)
    for i in 1:nrows
        for j in 1:i
            Swages[i] += wagedistarray[j,2]*wagedistarray[j,1]
        end
    end

    Gwages=Swages[1]*wagedistarray[1,2]
    for i in 2:nrows
        Gwages+=wagedistarray[i,2]*(Swages[i]+Swages[i-1])
    end

    return 1-(Gwages/Swages[length(Swages)])

end

wagedistarray=zeros(10000,2)
for i in 1:size(wagedistarray,1)
   wagedistarray[i,1]=1
   wagedistarray[i,2]=1/10000
end

@time result=gini(wagedistarray)
```

- Time before: `5.913907256 seconds (4000481676 bytes allocated, 25.37% gc time)`
- Time after: `0.134799301 seconds (507260 bytes allocated)`
- Time after (second run): `elapsed time: 0.123665107 seconds (80112 bytes allocated)`

The primary problems are that `Swages` was a global variable (wasn't living in the function) which is not a good coding practice, but more importantly is a [performance killer](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/). The other thing I noticed was `length(wagedistarray[:,1])`, which makes a copy of that column and then asks its length - that was generating some extra "garbage". The second run is faster because there is some compilation time the very first time the function is run.

You crank performance even higher using `@inbounds`, i.e.

```
function gini(wagedistarray)
    nrows = size(wagedistarray,1)
    Swages = zeros(nrows)
    @inbounds for i in 1:nrows
        for j in 1:i
            Swages[i] += wagedistarray[j,2]*wagedistarray[j,1]
        end
    end

    Gwages=Swages[1]*wagedistarray[1,2]
    @inbounds for i in 2:nrows
        Gwages+=wagedistarray[i,2]*(Swages[i]+Swages[i-1])
    end

    return 1-(Gwages/Swages[length(Swages)])
end
```

which gives me `elapsed time: 0.042070662 seconds (80112 bytes allocated)`

Finally, check out this version, which is actually faster than all and is also the most accurate I think:

```
function gini2(wagedistarray)
    Swages = cumsum(wagedistarray[:,1].*wagedistarray[:,2])
    Gwages = Swages[1]*wagedistarray[1,2] +
                sum(wagedistarray[2:end,2] .* 
                        (Swages[2:end]+Swages[1:end-1]))
    return 1 - Gwages/Swages[end]
end
```

Which has `elapsed time: 0.00041119 seconds (721664 bytes allocated)`. The main benefit was changing from a O(n^2) double for loop to the O(n) `cumsum`.

Answer (score 5):

IainDunning has already provided a good answer with code that is fast enough for practical purposes (the function `gini2`). If one enjoys performance tweaking, one can get an additional speed increase of a factor 20 by avoiding temporary arrays (`gini3`). See the following code that compares the performance of the two implementations:

```
using TimeIt

wagedistarray=zeros(10000,2)
for i in 1:size(wagedistarray,1)
   wagedistarray[i,1]=1
   wagedistarray[i,2]=1/10000
end

wages = wagedistarray[:,1]
wagefrequencies = wagedistarray[:,2];

# original code
function gini2(wagedistarray)
    Swages = cumsum(wagedistarray[:,1].*wagedistarray[:,2])
    Gwages = Swages[1]*wagedistarray[1,2] +
                sum(wagedistarray[2:end,2] .* 
                        (Swages[2:end]+Swages[1:end-1]))
    return 1 - Gwages/Swages[end]
end

# new code
function gini3(wages, wagefrequencies)
    Swages_previous = wages[1]*wagefrequencies[1]
    Gwages = Swages_previous*wagefrequencies[1]
    @inbounds for i = 2:length(wages)
        freq = wagefrequencies[i]
        Swages_current = Swages_previous + wages[i]*freq
        Gwages += freq * (Swages_current+Swages_previous)
        Swages_previous = Swages_current
    end
    return 1.0 - Gwages/Swages_previous
end

result=gini2(wagedistarray) # warming up JIT
println("result with gini2: $result, time:")
@timeit result=gini2(wagedistarray)

result=gini3(wages, wagefrequencies) # warming up JIT
println("result with gini3: $result, time:")
@timeit result=gini3(wages, wagefrequencies)
```

The output is:

```
result with gini2: 0.0, time:
1000 loops, best of 3: 321.57 µs per loop
result with gini3: -1.4210854715202004e-14, time:
10000 loops, best of 3: 16.24 µs per loop
```

`gini3` is somewhat less accurate than `gini2` due to sequential summation, one would have to use a variant of [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation) to increase accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [PovertyAndInequalityMeasures.jl](https://github.com/grahamstark/PovertyAndInequalityMeasures.jl), which does Ginis but also a bunch of other inequality and poverty measures (Atkinson indexes and so on). In real data there are often oddities such as negative wages and incomes.